# Convert only some columns names to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, list, datetime

I have dataframe with the following columns names:

```
print(df.columns)

Index(['name','city','age' ,'geometry', '2020-05-19', '2020-05-09', '2019-12-11',
       '2020-02-24', '2020-05-04', '2020-05-14', '2020-04-04', '2019-11-21',
       '2020-04-19', '2020-05-29', '2020-03-30', '2020-05-24', '2020-04-29',
       '2020-03-20', '2020-01-05', '2020-02-09', '2019-12-31', '2019-12-01',
       '2020-03-25', '2019-12-16', '2020-03-10', '2019-11-06', '2020-06-03',
       '2020-03-15', '2020-04-24', '2019-11-01', '2020-02-29', '2020-02-14',
       '2019-12-06', '2019-11-11', '2020-02-19', '2020-04-14', '2020-01-10',
       '2019-12-26', '2020-04-09'],
      dtype='object')
```

As you can see, the order of the dates columns is not correct. I would like to reorder those columns to be on the right order.

I ahve tried to do it by slicing the list of columns names,change only the dates and then put it back together but I got error

> TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations

This is how I tried to do that:

```
time_cols=pd.to_datetime(df.columns[10:])
df.columns[4:]=time_cols
df.columns


----> 3 df.columns[4:]=time_cols
TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations
```

My end goal is to change the type of the date columns to datetime so I can sort them .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, you can slice index/column but cannot modify individual elements. You can, however, replace the whole thing:

```
# 4 or 10?
time_cols=pd.to_datetime(df.columns[4:])

df.columns = list(df.columns[:4]) + list(time_cols)
```